# jQuery Validation plugin for file fields not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to limit the type of files a user can upload, using the jQuery validation plugin by using the `accept` method.

It works in the plugin examples page, but not for me.

Check this page: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/file_input.html when it says accept: "text/plain" the select file window only display text files in the folder. Which is a good thing.

When I do it (a little differently) I fail. I can see all files in a folder. How do I do this right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-js">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>I'm stuck</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="itemImage" class="itemImage">
    <label for="itemImage" generated="true" class="error itemImage"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" class="imageForm" id="submitbutton">
</form>
</body>
</html>

$("#imageForm").validate({
    rules: {
        itemImage: {
            required: true,
                accept: "text/plain"
        },
    },
    messages: {
        itemImage: {
            required: "Please select a text file",
            accept: "Only text files"
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#imageForm` instead of `#image` and enclose your `code` in `script tag` like,

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#imageForm").validate({
            rules: {
                itemImage: {
                    required: true,
                    accept: "text/plain"
                },
            },
            messages: {
                itemImage: {
                    required: "Please select a text file",
                    accept: "Only text files"
                },
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/MEK8G/)

Comment: What going wrong is, in the demo he has, when he specifies "text/plain", you can only see .txt files in the select file window. That's what I'm trying to achieve here, but it wont work. In your demo its the same thing. A user can see all the files.

Comment: @Norman, your _expectations_ are broken, not the demo.  The validation plugin will only give you a validation error message if the wrong kind of file is selected, that is all... it can not filter the files in the file browser window.

Comment: @Sparky It does filter files in the file browser window. It works in Chrome, but not in Mozilla. Try with the link I posted.

Comment: @Norman, you're confusing the HTML5 `accept` attribute with the `accept` rule/method of the validation plugin.  They are not the same thing.  The filtering will only occur if the browser can handle the HTML5 `accept` attribute.  See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#File_inputs

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I'm trying to limit the type of files a user can upload, using the jQuery validation plugin by using the accept method."*

You cannot, as that's not a function of the jQuery Validation plugin.   The Validation plugin will only give a validation error message *after* the file is selected.  It does not filter the content of the file browser window.  After all, if this were really the case, you'd never see a validation error and you wouldn't need to set an error message.

I think you're confusing the HTML5 `accept` attribute with the `accept` rule/method of the validation plugin.  They are not the same thing.  The filtering of file types within the file browser window will only occur if the Internet browser can handle the HTML5 `accept` attribute.

**For your reference:**

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/07-accept.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#File_inputs